# Order By Case With Text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of subjects which I need to sort - if the subject is a core subject then it needs to come first (sorted by SortOrder), if it is not a core subject then it needs to sorted alphabetically.

I've set up a fiddle with an example table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4b80eb/1

And the code I've tried is:

```
SELECT * FROM subject
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN IsCore=1 THEN SortOrder
    ELSE [Description]
    END
```

I get this error 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Science' to data type int.'.

I was hoping to get subjects in the following order:

- Maths
- Reading
- Writing
- Art
- Computing
- Science

Can anybody suggest how I should be doing the sort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `CASE` expression returns a scalar value, and uses [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to determine the return type. Clearly `SortOrder` is an `int`, and so has a higher data type precedence that the `varchar` datatype that `Description` is. Therefore you need to use a few expressions. I *assume* you want rows that have `IsCore = 1` first, which are then ordered by `SortOrder`, and then use the column `Description`.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN IsCore = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         CASE WHEN IsCore = 1 THEN SortOrder END,
         Description;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `IsCore` is always 0/1, you *could* express this using a single condition as:

```
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IsCore DESC,
                                     SortOrder * - IsCore,
                                     Description
                           )
```

Or:

```
ORDER BY ORDER BY IsCore DESC,
         SortOrder * - IsCore,
         Description
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4b80eb/18) is a SQLfiddle.

However, Larnu's solution is the more interpretable one.

Comment: @forpas . . .  Thank you.  Actually, the right solution is even simpler.

Comment: It can be even simpler if you remove row_number() which is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM subject
ORDER BY 
  IsCore DESC, 
  CASE IsCore WHEN 1 THEN [SortOrder] END,
  [Description]
```

The `CASE` statement is needed only to sort the rows with `IsCore = 1`.
See the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4b80eb/11).
Results:

```
SubjectId   SortOrder   Description IsCore
3           1           Maths       1
1           2           Reading     1
2           3           Writing     1
5           5           Art         0
6           6           Computing   0
4           4           Science     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
SELECT [SubjectId], [SortOrder], [Description], [IsCore] 
FROM subject
ORDER BY IsCore DESC, -- Everything with 1 in IsCore will come first
CASE WHEN IsCore = 1 
    THEN [SortOrder] -- use SortOrder for IsCore 1
    ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Description]) -- row number is alphabeticaly oredered
END
```

Note that a case expression must return compatible data type in all it's branches, meaning that it only returns a single data type, which is the highest precedence type from the set of types in all it's branches.